# how to find max 2 element in 10 element less complexity in java?

Tags: java

can you please tell me how to find max 2 element in 10 element less complexity in java .
I do like this but it complexity is too high .i need to reduce that
Algo

```
take max =a[0]

for(int i =0;i<10;i++){

if(a[i]>max)
max=a[i]

}
```

Second way to sort the array using bubble sort then find the last 2 element ?

Comment: that's the fastest way you can really do it... also, *bubble sort*?!?! Really?

Comment: You can sort your array using a mergesort/heapsort/quicksort which are in `O(n log n)` and then take the 2 last elements of the array (`O(1)`)

Comment: you could start the loop from index 1 since you already initialized max with a[0]

Comment: @A4L That won't change the complexity (still `O(n)`) and he didn't set the max with a[0], it's just for initialisation. =))

Comment: @ZouZou I know, but still saves one loop iteration :)

Comment: is there any one who said reverse bubble sort

Comment: Instead of resorting to sorting the array, you can simply do the following:

Keep a largestValue and a secondLargestValue
Loop through the entire array once, for each element:
Check to see if the current element is greater than largestValue:
If so, assign largestValue to secondLargestValue, then assign the current element to largestValue (think of it as shifting everything down by 1)
If not, check to see if the current element is greater than secondLargestValue
If so, assign the current element to secondLargestValue
If not, do nothing.
O(n) run time

O(1) space requirement

Comment: @constantlearner May you suggest this as an answer =)

Comment: *"...complexity is too high"*: How do you know if you've never even tried? If you *really* want a good learning experience, attempt this problem on your own. Thoroughly think through what you are trying to do. Before you write each line of code, ask yourself "What does this line do and how does it contribute to what I am trying to accomplish?" If you run in to a problem, try and figure it out **yourself** first, it is the only way you're going to learn.

Comment: give some good example

Comment: I think that using sorting algorithms and make complexity analysis is totally useless on a 10 numbers loop like that. Furthermore the solution is so simple that you can make it with a single iteration.

Comment: i saw some user write about reverse bubble sort

Comment: @Rohit Stop looking for the easy way out. At least make an attempt.. Unless, you have no desire to learn. In which case, why even bother programming?

Answer (score 2):

```
Instead of sorting the array, you can simply do the following:
Keep a largestValue and a secondLargestValue
Loop through the entire array once, for each element:
Check to see if the current element is greater than largestValue:
If so, assign largestValue to secondLargestValue, then assign the current element to largestValue (think of it as shifting everything down by 1)
If not, check to see if the current element is greater than secondLargestValue
If so, assign the current element to secondLargestValue
If not, do nothing.
O(n) run time

O(1) space requirement
```

Comment: +1 for not spoon-feeding.

Comment: what to initialize that Keep a largestValue and a secondLargestValue

Comment: what is the starting value of  largestValue and a secondLargestValue

Comment: and what if user want 3 or nth largest element

Comment: The QuickSelect algorithm to find kth largest

Comment: can you add that in your anwser

Comment: please give eample if possible

Comment: ok will post it refer this algo do it yourself http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/

Answer (score -1):

```
max =a[0];
max2 = a[0];

for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{

   if(a[i]>max)
   {   
      max2=max;
      max=a[i];
      continue;
   }
   if(a[i]>max2||max2==max)
   {
       max2=a[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: -1 I don't care if this is correct, at least give the OP the opportunity to figure it out on his own...

Comment: No problem, an emotional vote is still a vote...

Comment: Your code doesn't work if the largest value is stored at index 0.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Just edited to handle that case also